# org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

While trying to insert into database, Iam getting below Stack Trace -

StackTrace":"org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0

Any idea, why do we get this exception and the resolution. This issue is occuring intermittently and I am not observing it every time I hit my service.

Comment: You can go with table level locking in Database then run the Batch Job. It will resolve.

Comment: @LovaChittumuri : Can you guide me on table level locking. Also to inform, we are doing Java code level changes and have no access at table level. We can make changes from our Entities and DTOs.

Comment: No Need to do any thing in Java.

Comment: You should implement the locking concept on table which you using for above issue.(in Data Base)

Comment: At table level, can you suggest me the steps? It would be helpful.

Comment: access this url 
 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9015.htm

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` is the following:

Let's say you have a multi-threaded process that is supposed to delete number of records in your database.

Each thread executes the same code, e.g.:

```
Foo foo = repository.findById(id);
reposiroty.delete(foo);
```

Let's say that *thread A* found `Foo` entity by `id = 1`, and before *thread A* have gotten to `reposiroty.delete(foo);`, *thread B* also acquired `Foo` entity with `id = 1`.

So after `Foo` with `id = 1` is deleted by *thread A*, *thread B* will try to do the same thing, but since `Foo` with `id = 1` is already will be deleted at that time, *thread B* will throw `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException`.

Hence, *thread B* was hoping to delete the acquired entity, but this entity was already deleted by the time *thread B* actually started to perform the deletion.

As an option, you may catch `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` and implement some logic based on this scenario.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as OP, with an insert statement. Based on this explanation, I would expect the record to already exist and thus no second insert was possible. However, after carefully controlling the environment there was only one thread active and it threw this exception. Nothing got inserted in the database. So what exactly is being locked here?

Comment: It only means that somehow in your code there's some other transaction which has commited the changes to the record you are about to update. I'd suggest to review your code more carefully.

Comment: If that were the case, shouldn't I see a record in my database? Like, the "second insert" fails, but the "first" was committed successfully? I get what you're trying to say, but because my table is completely empty (and there is obviously no part of my code that performs a delete query)  I can't grasp why it fails on an insert.